# Winbatch how to set focus on next editbox?

Tags: automation

How to set focus on next editbox? I have dialog with focused first editobx, I filled data by SendKey() function. But I don't know, how to switch to next editbox. I am using Winbatch.

Code:

```
Delay(3);for switch app
top = WinGetactive( )
SendKeysTo(top, "my data")
```

`SendKeysTo(top, "{TAB}")` and also `ENTER` doesn't work. I don't know why... Maybe using something like `setFocus` function. But there is only `cSetFocus()`, working with ID's. But IDs are generated after running dialog every time.

Comment: The `Tab` key is normally used to move between fields on a dialog.

Comment: sorry DavidPostill, forgot to say, that: SendKeysTo(top, "{TAB}") and also ENTER doesn't work. I don't know why... Maybe using something like setFocus function. But there is only cSetFocus(), working with ID's. But IDs are generated after running dialog every time.

Comment: OK. Please [edit] the question to include the new information.